# how to add icon to a module on the menu of application?

Tags: odoo-11

i'm using odoo 11 and i have installed open HRMS core which install a specific theme. After that i have installed another module which named overtime (bt_hr_overtime_automatic) to satisfy my needs but the problem is in the menu  of the apps the new module doesn't has a icon and i want to add one(Ps: the module has a picture named "icon.png" in the folder /static/description/). Any idea on how to do that ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use **"web_icon"** in your menu to show your own icon. Save your icon in a directory. Size can be **256x256** File format should be ***.ico***

*Don't forget to upgrade your module after adding this code. Sometimes cache will show the old icon, if so try this in incognito mode or clear the cache*

```
web_icon="your_module_name,static/description/icon.ico".
```

**Example Code:**

```
<menuitem name="Overtime" id="your_menu_id" action="your_action_id" web_icon="your_module_name,static/description/icon.ico"/>
```

**Front End:**

If you want to add it in front end Go to
**Settings-->Technical Settings-->Menu Item-->Your Menu-->Web Icon File** Please refer screen shot

[image: icon for menu in odoo]

Answer (score 0):

First: create static folder inside your module directory .
Second: create description folder inside static folder.
Third: Make sure that your icon image is in png format .. like : icon.png .. and put it in static/description/
Finally: Restart Odoo Server and refresh your browser .
i tried it with odoo12 and it works